# How to link an entity with database?

Tags: session, symfony, entity-relationship, entitymanager, flush

I have a complex entity with many relations, so I need many forms in many pages to create one. Therefore, I use a session to keep my entity.
Everything is going okay, but when comes the time to flush, the entity manager returns the "entity through relationship is not configured to cascade persist" thinking that some entities are new but they're actually stored in db !

For instance, I create a User with a ManyToOne Group, using $u->setGroup(Group $group); ($group being an existing group from the db). When I put it in session, then get it back in another page and then flush it, the entity manager tries to create a whole new group, not knowing that it is an existing one in db.

I use a little trick to overcome this :

```
$u = $this->get('session')->get('userToAdd');
$group = $em->getRepository('MyBundle\Entity\Group')->find($u->getGroup()->getId());
$u->setGroup($group);
```

With this, EM will recognize the group stored in db and the flush will go just fine, but with my entity having so much relationships like this, it is very convenient to do this for every single one.

Any ideas for this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Before find group try to refresh $u object.

```
$em->refresh($u)
```

Comment: Entity is not managed. An entity is managed if its fetched from the database or registered as new through EntityManager#persist

:-(

Answer (score 0):

You have to do:

```
$em->merge($u);
```

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: I didn't know, sorry.